# gulp-imagemin сжимает только форматы .jpg и .svg

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, gulp

Почему **gulp-imagemin** сжимает только jpg и svg, а png, jpeg, gif и webp **игнорирует**?

*(под каждым форматом одно и то же изображение.)*

**tasks\images.js**

```
import webp from 'gulp-webp';
import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin';

export const images = () => {
  return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.images)
    .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
      app.plugins.notify.onError({
        title: 'IMAGES',
        message: 'Error: <%= error.message %>',
      }),
    ))
    .pipe(app.plugins.newer(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(webp())
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(app.gulp.src(app.path.src.images))
    .pipe(app.plugins.newer(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
      interlaced: true,
      optimizationLevel: 5, // 0 to 7
      verbose: true,
    }))
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(app.gulp.src(app.path.src.svg))
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(app.plugins.browsersync.stream());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

в patch.js указал путь к картинкам?

```py
// Получаем имя папки проекта
import * as nodePath from 'path'; //подключаем модули

const rootFolder = nodePath.basename(nodePath.resolve());

const buildFolder = `./docs`; // папка с результатом
const srcFolder = `./src`; // папка с исходниками

export const path = {
    build: {
        js: `${buildFolder}/js/`,
        css: `${buildFolder}/css/`,
        html: `${buildFolder}/`,
        images: `${buildFolder}/img/`,
        fonts: `${buildFolder}/fonts/`,
    },
    src: {
        images: `${srcFolder}/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}`,
        scss: `${srcFolder}/scss/style.scss`,
        css: `${srcFolder}/css/**/*.*`,
        js: `${srcFolder}/js/**/*.*`,
        html: `${srcFolder}/*.html`,
    },
    watch: { //слежка
        js: `${srcFolder}/js/**/*.js`,
        scss: `${srcFolder}/scss/**/*.scss`,
        css: `${srcFolder}/css/**/*.css`, 
        html: `${srcFolder}/**/*.html`,
        images: `${srcFolder}/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}`,
    },
    clean: buildFolder,
    buildFolder: buildFolder,
    srcFolder: srcFolder,
    rootFolder: rootFolder,
    ftp: ``
}
```